# Javascript yes or cancel

Tags: javascript

i have a question about the code below, whenever i click on cancel, the script still fires to launch the teamspeak server with the username null, how do i make it just cancel and do nothing? Thanks in advance for any help provided.

```
function checkCookie() {
var user=getCookie("username");
if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user + ". You will now be redirected to our teamspeak server.");
    window.location.assign("ts3server://ts3.demo.ga?port=9170&nickname=" +user);
} else {
   user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
   if (user != "" && user != null) {
       setCookie("username", user, 30);
   }
window.location.assign("ts3server://ts3.demo.ga?port=9170&nickname=" +user);
```

Comment: Move the last line (window.location...) so it comes after `setCookie`

Comment: Thanks for this, i didn't notice it after checking it again & again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest to do like this, where you check if user variable has a value (`user` validates to true) and with at least one character (`user.length` is greater than 0).

Note, your last `window.location.assign("...")` needs to be within the last `if` statment

```
function checkCookie() {
  var user = getCookie("username");
  if (user && user.length > 0) {
    alert("Welcome again " + user + ". You will now be redirected to our teamspeak server.");
    window.location.assign("ts3server://ts3.demo.ga?port=9170&nickname=" +user);
  } else {
    user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
    if (user && user.length > 0) {
      setCookie("username", user, 30);
      window.location.assign("ts3server://ts3.demo.ga?port=9170&nickname=" +user);    
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think its because null != "" and therefore your first if condition will still be true. try to check if user != "" && user != null in your first if condition